# Laravel, Datatables, inefficient queries

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, datatables

Some developers have produced a PHP software using Laravel and Datatables.
When I see the database queries produced by the application, I find one that is very inefficient. Example (the list of involved columns changes from one software feature to another):

```
 select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as [row_count] from [assignments]
  left join [jobs] on [assignments].[id] = [jobs].[name] 
  left join [categories] on [categories].[id] = [jobs].[vol_cat_type]
   where ([assignments].[id] LIKE '%XYZ%' or [assignments].[person_id] LIKE '%XYZ%' or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[name_title] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[first_name] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    [assignments].[title] LIKE '%XYZ%' or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[gender] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [states_master] where [states_master].[identity] = [assignments].[current_state] and [states_master].[name] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or
        [assignments].[updated_datetime] LIKE '%XYZ%' or
        (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[nationality] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[place_of_birth] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[civil_status] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[email] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[date_of_birth] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1 or 
    (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[nationality2] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1
      or (select count(1) from [people] where [assignments].[person_id] = [people].[person_id] and [people].[skype] LIKE '%XYZ%') >= 1))
       count_row_table
```

The tables involved are big, and these queries not only happen to take 20-30 seconds to execute, but also affect the general performances of the server.
What I don't like are the many LIKE applied to all the columns, especially to those where this is applied to non-strings (like the last modified date).
My proposal would be to:

1) Use = instead of LIKE for all non-string: numbers, single-characters codes like gender M/F, booleans

2) Configure the full-text search that is included in Microsoft SQL Server, and write CONTAINS(column,'XYZ') instead of LIKE

The objection from the developers is that Laravel and Datatables produce these queries, and there is nothing we can do about it.

Is it possible to configure Laravel and Datatables, without of course altering library code, specifying for every column whether to use LIKE, = or CONTAINS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent is generally used to create more simple Model queries.

For more complex SQL queries, use the query builder.

This is an example from the documentation on how to use it.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

You can also use raw sql if you like.

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries